# Привиденьческий/привиденьчиский

Tags: орфография, словообразование, прилагательные, суффиксы

Как правильно?

> Он привиденьческим/привиденьчиским голосом сказал что-то на ухо мне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно — **привиденческий**. Суффиксов *-ень-* и *-чиск-* в языке нет.

Привидение (*при/вид/**ениj**/е*) ↠ привиденческий (*при/вид/**ен**/**ческ**/ий*);
поведение ↠ по/вед/ен/ческ/ий;
приключение ↠ приключ/ен/ческ/ий.

*Мы с ней живем на шестом этаже. И голуби на шестом. Загадили балкон, карнизы, подоконники. Орут **привиденческими** голосами, дерутся, любятся — раздражают. Окно открытым оставишь — утром по всей кухне гуано, как на коралловых островах Индийского океана* (В. Конецкий. Начало нового пути, или Шок от этологии).

***Привиденческий** голос диспетчера все так же гулко вздыхал и бормотал о чем-то своем, железнодорожном* (А. Воронова. Лунное танго).

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, **с голосами** надо быть аккуратнее. Это **смотря кто приходил.**

Кроме привидения, мог зайти **провидец** со своим провидением/предвидением. Тогда голос будет провидческим.

**ПРОВИДЧЕСКИЙ**, -ая, -ое. Книжн. к Провидец и Провидчество. П. дар. П-ое слово писателя. Большой толковый словарь

Раньше еще были **провиденческие** голоса, но потом их отменили  [https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/365459/провиденческий](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/365459/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)